# Editing a question where the edit will change the question's meaning

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette

I have posted an answer to [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/38910/do-oral-vaccines-exist). The current question is "Do oral vaccines exist?" In the comments, it has become clear that the user meant to ask something more like "Have any crop plants been genetically modified to provide vaccination when the plant is eaten?"

What is the question-editing etiquette here? I can see several alternatives:

1. The user should update their question so that it more closely
   matches their intention,
2. I should update the question so that it
   closely matches what I think the user's intention is,
3. The question should be left as-is, and someone should create a separate question that matches the user's intention,
4. I should stop worrying about minutiae and go look at other questions.

Comment: Related discussion from my other stack exchange communities:

http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/what-to-do-when-the-original-question-is-transformed-considerably-after-getting/1180#1180

http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254528/editing-a-question-to-include-a-comment-left-by-asker

Answer (score 2):

I think you should tell them to post a new question since it is quite different than the current question, which you already answered.

Comment: I agree in principle - but in the meantime, WYSIWYG has requested the user update their question, which also solves the problem.